# adding a system call for getting hardware tx rx queue length of atheros ath9k_htc driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, wifi, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I'm doing this project which involves getting TX/RX queue length of a USB NIC. Goal is to modify *ath9k_htc* driver of device (which is also part of Linux kernel tree) and add a queue-length system call in the kernel.

I was able to get the TX queue length. After `insmod`'ing the driver module I'm able to print any message till the point of USB-bus registration, but flow of the driver is such that it requires interrupt by upper layers to send a packet in ring buffer and then to hardware queue, and because of that (I am assuming because of interrupt, printk is not working properly) I'm not able to print anything using `printk` or `pr_info` at this side of code.

So my question is, can we debug *ath9k_htc* by any other method and is it possible to add a functionality in a driver as a system-call ?

Comment: Can you share any relevant code snippets?

Comment: "I am assuming because of interrupt, printk is not working properly" - No, `printk` works correctly even inside interrupt handler. Your problem is somewhere else, but without the code we cannot help you.

Comment: a system call seems overkill for this requirement. Have you looked into other ways to configure a driver? Have you looked at the proc/sys filesystem?